# Task list - alert on completed status

Tags: 2010, 2007, alert, tasks

I have a task list and I have set up an alert so that it sends one when the task is completed.

Does this only work on the default "completed" option? What if I added another option called "complete" or have removed the default "completed" and added a new "completed" one?

Comment: Can you please explain how you created the alert?

Comment: On a standard Task list, I went to the ribbon -> 'Alert Me' -> 'Set alert on this list', then chose the setting "Send me an alert when: A task becomes complete"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done some testing and here are my results:

- If you remove the default "Completed" option and re-add it, it will still trigger.
- If you remove the default "Completed" option and re-add it as "cOmPleTed", it will still trigger.